# laravel 8 store() & index() functions doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, controller

Salam i am new in laravel i try to show & store data and index() and store() functions doesn't work!!

its display as result
500 | SERVER ERROR

this is the controller code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Enseignant;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class EnseignantController extends Controller
{
   /**
    * Display a listing of the resource.
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */

public function index()
   {
   
  return response()->json(Enseignant::all(),200);
       }




public function store(Request $request)
   {
  
try{

$enseigante = Enseignant::create($request->all());

     return response($enseigante,201);
     }catch(Throwable $e){
    report($e);
    return false;
     }
   }
```

Comment: In .env file edit to `APP_DEBUG=true` to display you the errors

Comment: its already true!

Comment: try `php artisan config:clear && php artisan cache:clear` or you can delete php files at `root-app/bootstrap/cache/*.php`

Comment: A 500 error is exceptionally generic and could be caused by a multitude of issues. Have a look in the laravel.log file and also the server log files to see if they give a better indication as to the reasons for the error.

Comment: where i find "laravel.log" and server log files??

Comment: when execute index function in browser it's display :: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @romaissa go to `storage/logs/laravel.log` and see what happening on there.

Comment: i haven't this file !!

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the create method in the controller, you need to make sure that the fillable things are mentioned in the model.

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'email',
    'password',
];
```

And to retrieve the data you can use.

```
    public function index()
{
    $admins = admin::all();
    return view('totalUser', compact('admins'));
}
```

To show the data on your view you can do this:

```
@foreach($admins as $admin) 
    <p>{{$admin->name}}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I am sure from my fillable, but in controller i return json data

Comment: The problem the same code work before i don't know what happen now :'(  i don't change any thing!!

Answer (score 0):

What's the error we cannot understand just by the status code share the actual error